# How can we track hashtags with the new facebook hashtag implementation

Tags: facebook, api, tracking, counting, hashtag

Since Facebook introduced hashtags, I've been interested in finding out more about them. Can someone point me in the direction of possibly tracking the hashtags similar to how twitter allows us access to pull hashtag data via their API. I can count mentions, get usernames, and the tweets. Has Facebook launched anything similar? I can't find any documentation online.

Answer (score 14):

There is currently no API for the hashtags feature on Facebook

*edit*: there was however a public posts search function which will return some public posts with a certain hashtag if you use that hashtag as the search string in API version 1.0 - there is no equivalent in version 2.0 onwards

It ignores the # symbol in the matching though, so a search for '#omg' will find posts with 'omg' too.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search )

Comment: kinda sux tho.. i thought we might or would have been able to do some cool things with this

Comment: @Igy, any update to this ?  hashtag searches still not available??

Comment: Still no hashtag-specific features anywhere in the API as of today (August 28). The method Igy suggested in his edit is the best way to do it so far.

Comment: The Igy method is good but doesn't work anymore as soon as there is a picture attached to the post. A real hashtag search would be nice to be included in the api.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook recently announced [new tools for surfacing conversations](https://newsroom.fb.com/News/706/New-Tools-for-Surfacing-Conversations-on-Facebook) with the launch of [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) which :

> displays a real-time feed of public posts for a specific word

Unfortunately, that tool is restricted to a small set of "trusted" users for now...