# Justin's realtime page updates

Tags: facebook

Say I've got a facebook application: JustinFanClub

For that app, I'm interested in tracking [Justin Bieber's page](https://www.facebook.com/JustinBieber) feed updates, in realtime.

In order to, and [according to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime), I need to ask Justin a permission (`access_token`) to manage **all** his pages (with [`manage_pages`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/page-permissions/) permission) before being able to *install* (`POST /JustinBieber/tabs`) my app to his page...

--

But hey!

Why do I need to do all this? Justin Bieber's page feed isn't public after all? Why should I request something from him, just to receive his public updates?

Really I don't get it...
Maybe I'm totally wrong and/or have missed something.

Can you confirm there is no more simple way of just getting realtime page updates (without having to require any permission for what's already public)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114210/how-can-we-track-hashtags-with-the-new-facebook-hashtag-implementation/20164334#answer-20164334

Answer (score 1):

The RSS feed of the page can help you?
If yes, take a look here at this address:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=67253243887

The format can be rss20 (RSS 2.0) or atom10 (Atom 1.0) (if needed, see [this link](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2006/03/30/rss-vs-atom-whats-the-big-deal/) for their difference)

To get the page ID, insert the page above at http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Comment: Could be a workaround, but without realtime feature which really matters here... PS: Can you give the atom link? https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom&id=67253243887 does not work...

Comment: This is the Atom link (the correct is atom10, not atom, sorry for my mistake. I'll edit the post to correct this): https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=67253243887. I really don't know another way to do this, at least for now. If I think something more about, I will post here.

Comment: Thx @saulotoledo, your answer doesn't totally satisfy the question (realtime) but at least it brings information about feeds, I +1 for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

The realtime updates functionality is intended for use by people acting on behalf of the admins of a page (hence the requirement to install the app onto the page) - you can't subscribe to realtime updates for arbitrary users or pages, only those who've authorised your app.

To read information about another page or user, you need to poll the API using the access token of someone authorised to see that page's content

Comment: "someone authorised to see that page's content"? but pages' content is public! That's exactly the paradox I'm describing... Do you get the paradox? Or is it only me?

Comment: Not really, you're allowed see it (assuming no demographic restrictions or targeted content), but you must be acting on behalf of an admin if you want realtime notifications of new content on the page. otherwise, you need to poll

Comment: Well, polling solution is weird: for its own interest, I think Facebook should provide solution to avoid developers polling its servers... Maybe this is why the Public Feed API(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) is for (see my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114210/how-can-we-track-hashtags-with-the-new-facebook-hashtag-implementation/20164334#answer-20164334) but unfornatly restricted to some users for now... @Igy, your thoughts?

Comment: do you know if it's possible requesting Facebook for an access to their restricted Public Feed API, or do I just need to wait... Do you think it worth a try or is it useless?

Comment: There's currently no application process for that API, it's only made available to existing media partners as far as I know