# Scraping Posts of a hashtag on Facebook

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, hashtag

Is there any way I can scrape all the posts of a particular hashtag? Basically we're running a contest and we're not making an app and rather doing it the simple way, enter by putting ‪#‎hashtag‬, so any idea how can that be done? I recently found out that the API don't access that anymore. But I can't cancel that as we're in middle of the contest now.

Answer (score 2):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook (and impossible in this case anyway), and there is no way to do this with the API. In other words: there is no way at all.

More information: [How can we track hashtags with the new facebook hashtag implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114210/how-can-we-track-hashtags-with-the-new-facebook-hashtag-implementation)